# Fetch Content from A Div Class using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

How to Fetch Content in A Div Class using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).
Here i want to fetch content from a div class like:

```
<div class="post" imposition="usermanual">Some Content </div>
```

So, what is the way to fetch content using this div class `post`?
I have tried this code but dont works:

```
$es = $html->find('.post');
$es = $html->find('div.post'); // also try this
$es = $html->find('div[class="post"]'); // also try this
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the *Magic Attributes* tab of [How to access the HTML element's attributes](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access), you'll find how to access an object's `innertext` property. There's also a `plaintext` property.

```
$es = $html->find('div[class="post"]', 0);
echo $es->innertext; // Some Content
```